# Making a child class Singleton whose parent extends Thread

Tags: spring, singleton

So, i have a class like below

```
    public class ClassA extends Thread {
    protected final InnerClassA innerA;
    
    public ClassA(InnerClassA innerclassA){
    super(innerclassA.id);
    innerA = innerclassA;
    }
    
    //override methods like run, interrupt
    
    public static class InnerClassA {
    //some methods of this class
    }
    
    public static class InnerClassB {
    //constructor and some methods
    }
    }
```

I want to create a new class (ClassB) which will extend ClassA and also, make ClassB as singleton. To achieve this, do I need to override
all methods of ClassA or only some and make use of existing methods from
ClassA?

Comment: Not clear what your goal is here. Also unclear what Spring has to do with it.

Comment: @NathanHughes i have ClassA in package module1.package1 and i want to create ClassB in package module2.package1 and ClassB should work same as ClassA and should be singleton.

Comment: my modules are as follows:
-MainDirectory
--module1.package1(ClassA)
--module2.package1(ClassB)